# React JS. Получить параметр из вложенного роута

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть настроенный react-router (react-router 2.*):

```
<Router  history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="list/:id" component={List} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Как получить в компоненте `{App}` свойство `:id` вложенного роута `{List}`?

В компоненте `{App}` рендер происходит след. образом:

```
<div className="wrapper">
    <MenuList />
    {this.props.children}
</div>
```

Смысл заключается в следующем:

Мне необходимо произвести какие-то действия с `id` в `MenuList`, например, установить активное состояние пункта.

Как это сделать наиболее правильно и в стиле React'а?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Внутри компонента *App* оно будет в `this.props.params.id`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?